# Meaning of 'es hat mir sehr gut gefallen.'

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, german-to-english

What should be the meaning of the sentence: "es hat mir sehr gut gefallen."

As per the translator, it means 'I liked it very well'

But i think it should mean 'it suits me very well'

Why am I wrong?

Comment: What makes you think it means 'it suits me very well'?

Answer (score 2):

The translator is wrong, 'I liked it very well' is not even correct English. It should be "I liked it very **much**".

Since you don't say why you think "it suits me very well" would be a good translation, there's no way of telling why you are wrong.

Comment: what does gefallen means? Doesn't it mean 'suit'. The google translator showed this. So I assumed that the sentence can mean "it suits me very well"

Comment: @akshitbhatia It means to please someone. Dict.leo.org does give 'suit' as a possible translation, but I consider that a very unusual translation. "Passen" is better for "to suit"